# C++ Thread inside a for loop causing big memory leak

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory, memory-leaks

I have been trying out using threads in my code and I've found that there was a memory leak after I added threads. Usually, the code took up 400MB, but after I added threads it rose to 900MB and continued to increase.

I made a test code that to see where the memory leak was coming from and I found it to be the thread inside the for loop. After a short wait, this test code used over 100MB and kept growing.
This code also slightly resembles the one I was working on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void foo(){}

int main()
{
    for(;;){
        std::thread Ding(foo);
        Ding.join();
    }
}
```

I am using Windows 7 with Code::Blocks 16.01 using the GNU GCC compiler version 4.9.2 and used task manager to see the memory usage.

Why does this code continuously increase its memory usage and how can I stop it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Stays at 520-530 K for me. *This code also slightly resembles the one I was working on.* That could be the reason.

Comment: On what compiler and OS are you observing this?

Comment: Constant 156KB on my PC, it may be a bug in your compiler. Check for newer versions.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I am using Windows 7 and using the GNU GCC compiler

Comment: @1Question yes, but what version?

Comment: @7raiden7 gcc (tdm-1) 4.9.2

Comment: 4.9 is pretty old, not fully-C++11 version.. technically this code should not produce any load at all, because function used for thread is empty.. optimized version  should collapse. If it is running in debugger like cdb.. I don't know, it might just case of storing data about threads and stack?

Comment: Try with 6.1.0 which is the latest stable. Also, as already mentioned above, all threads should spawn and die instantly as the body of the workers is empty. Try to compile with -O0 and put some printf's